# Блок со внутренней тенью лишь у двух краев

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте!

Такая задача: сделать див со внутренней тенью лишь у двух краев: верхнего и нижнего. При этом слева и справа тени быть не должно.

Сейчас я сделал это [вот так](http://jsfiddle.net/28ZWs/): один див на 25px выходит за окно, другой не дает растянуть body, пряча остатки первого.

Собственно вопрос: можно ли обойтись тут одним дивом и как?

Comment: Есть у меня такая мысль: так как фоном в любом случае идет текстура (без нее это не красиво), можно нарисовать тень на текстуре. Можно накладывать сразу несколько фонов — один полупрозрачный с тенью, другой — основной, третий — тень снизу. Вот только это может сильно перегрузить страницу, а там и так изображений куча... Короче пока что сижу на двух дивах.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 15px 15px  -15px #333 , inset 0 -15px 15px  -15px #333;
```

Тень будет только сверху и снизу. Посмотреть можно здесь: http://jsfiddle.net/shpQ4/2/

Тестировал только в IE 10, но думаю что работает во всех основных браузерах.

Расширенный пример: http://jsfiddle.net/TaA29/

Answer (score 2):

Онлайн генератор теней [CSS Box Shadow](http://greempage.ru/css-box-shadow) —
очень помог в своё время.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?